# Integral of $\int{\frac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t}} c(x, t) dx$ in $R^3$

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is how to calculate that integral

$\int{\frac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t}} c(x, t) dx$ in $R^3$

I know I have to use "integration by parts".
I'm not sure about how to perform this exactly.

My first thought was to argue that I can use Leibniz's rule and
move the partial derivative out of the integral, then I would be left
with c(x,t)*c(x,t) dx (where * means multiplication) - but this is wrong.

Note: I found that website with explanation, are these formally correct?
https://www.albert.io/blog/integration-by-parts-multivariable-calculus/

Edit: Sorry, * should be multiplication. I corrected the formula.

Thanks in advance,
Best regards

Comment: if $\ast$ means the multiplication, and if you meant $\int \ldots dt$, then look at the derivative of $f(t)^2$